# How to order items in timeline using visjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vis.js

I'm using visjs library in my project and i want to order the timeline's items, the red ones in the bottom and the others in top like this image.
[image: time_line]

heres my code:

```
 storyboard.getPositionDataByEvent= function (deviceId) {

            var url = servername+'api/position/'+deviceId;
            console.log("Inside getMaxChaufeeurId " + url);
            function onSuccess(response) {
                console.log("+++++youssef SUCCESS++++++");

                if (response.data.success != false) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify("toto :"+JSON.stringify(response.data.data)));
                    //$scope.MyData=response.data;

                    var isFirst = true;
                    var first, last;
                    var items = [];
                    var k;
                    var arrayList=[];
                    ///
                    var zFirst;
                    var zLast;

                    //vert
                    arrayList[44] = "#009900";
                    arrayList[87] = "#009900";
                    arrayList[69] = "#009900";

                    //rouge
                    arrayList[80] = "#e62e00";
                    arrayList[53] = "#e62e00";

                    //orange
                    arrayList[35] = "#ff8533";
                    //fushia --unknown event
                    arrayList[43] = " #cc0099";

                    //event 15
                    arrayList[15] = "#663300";

                    var colorArray=['red','green','#5561c1','#52b2da'];
                    //var el = document.createElement( 'html' );


                    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {

                        if(last != null && last.event != k.event) {
                            // alert('isLast');
                            if((last.event == 44 && k.event == 87) || (last.event == 44 && k.event == 69) || (last.event == 87 && k.event == 44) || (last.event == 87 && k.event == 69) ||
                                (last.event == 69 && k.event == 44) || (last.event == 69 && k.event == 87) || (last.event == 80 && k.event == 53)|| (last.event == 53 && k.event == 80) )  {

                            } else {
                                var itemHeight;
                                isFirst = true;
                                console.log(first.event + " - " + last.event );
                                var item = {};
                                // item.id = i;
                                if( last.event!=80 && last.event!=53 ){
                                    itemHeight=10;
                                } else{
                                    itemHeight=15;
                                   // item.group=2;
                                }

                                item.id=first.fixtime+'@'+ k.fixtime;


                                //item.content = "item " + i;
                                item.start = first.fixtime ;

                                //$scope.gg=item.start;
                                item.end = k.fixtime ;


                                var cal=moment.utc(moment(item.end,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(item.start,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");
                                //console.log(cal);
                                //$filter('date')(item.end, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                item.title='<div ><strong>date Début :</strong>'+$filter('date')(item.start, "HH:mm:ss")+
                                    '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Date fin :</strong>'+$filter('date')(item.end, " HH:mm:ss")+'<br/><strong>Duration :</strong>'+moment.utc(moment($filter('date')(item.end, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment($filter('date')(item.start, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")+'<br/>rrr<br/>jjjjj<br/>uuuu<br/>iiii</br>ujuuu<br/>ujuuuu<br/></div>';
                                item.style="height:14px;margin-top:"+$scope.marginTop+"px"+"!important;background-color:"+arrayList[last.event]+";border-color:"+arrayList[last.event];
                                items.push(item);
                            }
                        }

                        if(isFirst) {

                            isFirst = false;
                            first = k;

                        }

                    }

                    $scope.myVisData=new VisDataSet(items);
                    storyboard.initialisation($scope.myVisData);

                }




            };

            function onError(response) {
                console.log("-------getMaxChaufeeurId FAILED-------");

                console.log(response.data);
                console.log("Inside getMaxChaufeeurId error condition...");
            };

            //----MAKE AJAX REQUEST CALL to GET DATA----
            ajaxServicess.getData(url, 'GET', '').then(onSuccess, onError);

        };
```

heres the initialisation methode:

```
 storyboard.initialisation=function(items){

            //alert($scope.currentDate+' '+$scope.tomorrowDate);

            // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
            var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
            //$scope.currentDate
            //$scope.tomorrowDate



            var options = {

                width:'99%',
                min: $scope.currentDate,
                max:$scope.tomorrowDate,
                height:'200px',
                zoomable:false,

                showCurrentTime:true,
                stack:true,
                //to fix stack=false i have to change margin-top above
                //zoomMax:10,
                //zoomMin:10,
                //type:'background',
                //
                showMajorLabels:false,
                margin:{
                    axis:-4,
                    item:1
                },
                format:{
                    minorLabels: {
                        minute:'mm',
                        hour: "HH[h]"
                    }
                }
            };
            // Create a Timeline
            timeline = new vis.Timeline(container,items,options);



        }
```

any idea to order the items in my time line like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using groups is the way forward. You can put items for each row in the same group, and each group gets its own line in the timeline. You can also apply styles to a group, to save you from styling each item individually.

Read the documentation on groups here:
http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#groups